# How to customize a pre-trained model with our own dataset?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I am currently working on `Object detection`. I am using `Amazon Workspace` for training my model. I am using the model to `detect cars and bikes`. I have used a **pre-trained model** (which is `Faster-RCNN-Inception-V2` model) and customized it with my own dataset for 2 labels namely car and bike. It took me 5 hours to complete the training. Now I want to **modify my model for 2 more labels** (keeping to old ones) namely bus and auto. But I don't want to do the training from scratch as my model is already trained for cars and bikes. So is there any way that I can train my model only with the dataset of bus and auto, and after training it will detect all `4 objects(car, bike, bus, and auto)`?

Comment: Yes. just save your weights now that you've completed a full training.

Comment: Sorry, can you elaborate it a little bit

Comment: This is called transfer learning (what you've done in the first step of training) and basically reuse its pretrained weights for other task. You should simply continue learning with the weights that are able to predict your lastly added labels (car, bike) but now with (car, bike, bus, auto)

Comment: Okay thank you so much. I will do some research in this area.

Answer (score 0):

Load the saved model with pretrained weights. Remove last dense and 2 class softmax layer and add a new dense with 4 class softmax as your low level features are already trained. Now train this model with modified data.